# Matching date and time in 12hrs format

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am following this tutorial (https://towardsdatascience.com/build-your-own-whatsapp-chat-analyzer-9590acca9014) to build a WhatsApp analyzer.

This is the entire code from his tutorial -

```
def startsWithDateTime(s):
    pattern = '^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)(\d{2}|\d{4}), ([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]) -'
    result = re.match(pattern, s)
    if result:
        return True
    return False

def startsWithAuthor(s):
    patterns = [
        '([\w]+):',                        # First Name
        '([\w]+[\s]+[\w]+):',              # First Name + Last Name
        '([\w]+[\s]+[\w]+[\s]+[\w]+):',    # First Name + Middle Name + Last Name
        '([+]\d{2} \d{5} \d{5}):',         # Mobile Number (India)
        '([+]\d{2} \d{3} \d{3} \d{4}):',   # Mobile Number (US)
        '([+]\d{2} \d{4} \d{7})'           # Mobile Number (Europe)
    ]
    pattern = '^' + '|'.join(patterns)
    result = re.match(pattern, s)
    if result:
        return True
    return False

def getDataPoint(line):
    # line = 18/06/17, 22:47 - Loki: Why do you have 2 numbers, Banner?

    splitLine = line.split(' - ') # splitLine = ['18/06/17, 22:47', 'Loki: Why do you have 2 numbers, Banner?']

    dateTime = splitLine[0] # dateTime = '18/06/17, 22:47'

    date, time = dateTime.split(', ') # date = '18/06/17'; time = '22:47'

    message = ' '.join(splitLine[1:]) # message = 'Loki: Why do you have 2 numbers, Banner?'

    if startsWithAuthor(message): # True
        splitMessage = message.split(': ') # splitMessage = ['Loki', 'Why do you have 2 numbers, Banner?']
        author = splitMessage[0] # author = 'Loki'
        message = ' '.join(splitMessage[1:]) # message = 'Why do you have 2 numbers, Banner?'
    else:
        author = None
    return date, time, author, message


parsedData = [] # List to keep track of data so it can be used by a Pandas dataframe
conversationPath = 'chat.txt' 
with open(conversationPath, encoding="utf-8") as fp:

    fp.readline() # Skipping first line of the file (usually contains information about end-to-end encryption)

    messageBuffer = [] # Buffer to capture intermediate output for multi-line messages
    date, time, author = None, None, None # Intermediate variables to keep track of the current message being processed

    while True:
        line = fp.readline() 
        if not line: # Stop reading further if end of file has been reached
            break
        line = line.strip() # Guarding against erroneous leading and trailing whitespaces
        if startsWithDateTime(line): # If a line starts with a Date Time pattern, then this indicates the beginning of a new message
            print('true')
            if len(messageBuffer) > 0: # Check if the message buffer contains characters from previous iterations
                parsedData.append([date, time, author, ' '.join(messageBuffer)]) # Save the tokens from the previous message in parsedData
                messageBuffer.clear() # Clear the message buffer so that it can be used for the next message
                date, time, author, message = getDataPoint(line) # Identify and extract tokens from the line
                messageBuffer.append(message) # Append message to buffer

        else:
            messageBuffer.append(line) # If a line doesn't start with a Date Time pattern, then it is part of a multi-line message. So, just append to buffer
```

When I plug in my chat file - `chat.txt`, I noticed that my list `parsedData` is empty. After going through his code, I noticed what might be responsible for the empty list.
From his tutorial, his chats are in this format (24hrs) - 
`18/06/17, 22:47 - Loki: Why do you have 2 numbers, Banner?` but my chats are this format (12 hrs) - `[4/19/20, 8:10:57 PM] Joe: How are you doing`.

Reason why the `startsWithDateTime` function is unable to match any date and time.

Please how do I change the regex format in the `startsWithDateTime` function to match my chat format?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here.
First, your regex is looking for a date in the format DD/MM/YYYY, but the format you give is in M/DD/YYYY.
Second, the square brackets are not present in the first example you give, which succeeds, but are present in the second example.
Third, in looking at your regex, the problem isn't in the 12-hour v 24-hour time format per se, but in the fact that your regex is searching for a strictly 2-digit hour digit. When using 24-hour format, it is common to include a leading zero for single-digit hours (e.g., `08:10` for 8:10am), but in 12-hour format it is not (so your code would fail to find `8:10`.
You can fix your regular expression by changing the relevant section from

```
([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9])
```

to

```
([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{2})
```

The number in curly braces indicates how many examples of that character to look for, so in this case this expression will look for either one or two digits, then a colon, then exactly two digits.

Then the final regex would have to be

```
^\[(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2}|\d{4}), ([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})\ ([AP]M)\]
```

Example:

```
import re
a = '[4/19/20, 8:10:57 PM] Joe: How are you doing'
p = r'^\[(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2}|\d{4}), ([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})\ ([AP]M)\]'
re.findall(p, a)
#  [('4', '19', '20', '8', '10', '57', 'PM')]
```

Comment: Still empty. Here is the final pattern just in case I am missing something - 

pattern = '^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)(\d{2}|\d{4}), ([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(\ )([AP]M) -'

What might be the problem?

Comment: There were a few more fixes beyond just the 24-hour format. They should be edited now.